How do I connect my existing Visual Studio 2022 project to an existing github repository?
I set up a github repository to match the project I am working on in Visual Studio 2022. I did something wrong and only the project file exists. I followed a tutorial. But the tutorial was disappointing and the instruction was to drag the content of my project and I suppose I only uploaded the project file.
That was then. This is now. So far this is what I have done. In Visual studio I opened a command window by click on CTRL +  ` . Then using the .git file and its location from my github repository, I typed at the command line:

git clone https://github.com/Wm-M-Thompson/SharePointListCreation.git


No what do I do?

The link is not working so edit your question.
Step to follow
1- Visual Studio saves your version control so now know your date time
2- Go to GitHub and go to history
3- reiterate the version and save it.
4- VS code is used that after completing your code do push with comment so you can keep version control.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Sync local project to its existing GitHub repo

Clone Repo: Run

git clone https://github.com/Wm-M-Thompson/SharePointListCreation.git


Open Project:
In Visual Studio, open the .sln from the cloned repo.

Add Missing Files:
Right-click your project in Solution Explorer > Add > Existing Item and select all missing files.

Stage Changes:
In Git Changes, click Stage All to stage everything at once.

Commit & Push:
Write a commit message and click Commit All and Push.


This should sync all local project files to its existing GitHub repo.
